# Edit and find querystring parameter value

Tags: c#

First I want to say that I'm completely new to coding and although I've learned some basics a few years ago.

For now I'm trying to make a program that searches in an user inputted text. And replace some parts of that, then gives the new text back.

Like this:

> stormcloud-146919.appspot.com/purchase/listing/?global=ahNzfnN0b3JtY2xvdWQtMTQ2OTE5ckULEgNVSUQiEDEyNTA0NjQ5MDgzMjUyNDIMCxIGUGxheWVyGICAgICAgIAKDAsSDEl0ZW1JbnN0YW5jZRiAgICAgOSRCgw&coin=**3**&xpPlayer=**10**&sidekick1=ahNzfnN0b3JtY2xvdWQtMTQ2OTE5ckULEgNVSUQiEDEyNTA0NjQ5MDgzMjUyNDIMCxIGUGxheWVyGICAgICAgIAKDAsSDEl0ZW1JbnN0YW5jZRiAgICAkMmPCgw&xpSidekick1=**10**&sidekick2=ahNzfnN0b3JtY2xvdWQtMTQ2OTE5ckULEgNVSUQiEDEyNTA0NjQ5MDgzMjUyNDIMCxIGUGxheWVyGICAgICAgIAKDAsSDEl0ZW1JbnN0YW5jZRiAgICA0OqZCgw&xpSidekick2=**10**&k=ahNzfnN0b3JtY2xvdWQtMTQ2OTE5ciwLEgNVSUQiEDEyNTA0NjQ5MDgzMjUyNDIMCxIGUGxheWVyGICAgICAgIAKDA&l=ahNzfnN0b3JtY2xvdWQtMTQ2OTE5chQLEgdMaXN0aW5nGICAgID00JwKDA&

With the bold parts being searched and replaced by my custom text or digits.

Comment: My first idea was first to use replace but then I thougth that there was no way I could find those digits because they will change after a new input.
Then I've searched some things but I couldn't find anything

Comment: try use Indexof and insert method in c# little search will get you the ans,applied when coin= parameter is fixed same for all

Comment: You can consider using of `HttpUtility.ParseQueryString` [https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms150046(v=vs.110).aspx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms150046(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Sorry for being a noob in this, but could you please explain how it could help? And how I could use it?@SatishPatil

Comment: @Fabio AGain me being noob, how is this usable?

Comment: Do your users really input this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope you are looking to update some querystring parameter values.
You can use `HttpUtility.ParseQueryString()` for this.
Find the sample below.

```
var url = "stormcloud-146919.appspot.com/purchase/listing/?global=ahNzfnN0b3JtY2xvdWQtMTQ2OTE5ckULEgNVSUQiEDEyNTA0NjQ5MDgzMjUyNDIMCxIGUGxheWVyGICAgICAgIAKDAsSDEl0ZW1JbnN0YW5jZRiAgICAgOSRCgw&coin=3&xpPlayer=10&sidekick1=ahNzfnN0b3JtY2xvdWQtMTQ2OTE5ckULEgNVSUQiEDEyNTA0NjQ5MDgzMjUyNDIMCxIGUGxheWVyGICAgICAgIAKDAsSDEl0ZW1JbnN0YW5jZRiAgICAkMmPCgw&xpSidekick1=10&sidekick2=ahNzfnN0b3JtY2xvdWQtMTQ2OTE5ckULEgNVSUQiEDEyNTA0NjQ5MDgzMjUyNDIMCxIGUGxheWVyGICAgICAgIAKDAsSDEl0ZW1JbnN0YW5jZRiAgICA0OqZCgw&xpSidekick2=10&k=ahNzfnN0b3JtY2xvdWQtMTQ2OTE5ciwLEgNVSUQiEDEyNTA0NjQ5MDgzMjUyNDIMCxIGUGxheWVyGICAgICAgIAKDA&l=ahNzfnN0b3JtY2xvdWQtMTQ2OTE5chQLEgdMaXN0aW5nGICAgID00JwKDA&";
Console.WriteLine(url);
var uriBuilder = new UriBuilder(url);
var query = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(uriBuilder.Query);
query["coin"] = "4";
query["xpPlayer"] = "4";
query["xpSidekick1"] = "4";
query["xpSidekick2"] = "4";

uriBuilder.Query = query.ToString();
Console.WriteLine(uriBuilder.ToString());
```

See if that meets your requirements.
Remember to import System.Web namespace.

```
using System.Web;
```

More details on the code an be found here:
http://codeskaters.blogspot.ae/2016/12/c-update-querystring-values-in-url.html

Comment: Ok and how do I turn that into my txtblock? Sorry for those questions

Comment: What is txtblock. I guess its the textbox ui control.
It should be like: txtblock.Text = uriBuilder.ToString();

Comment: Nice! My last problem that I didn't find a solution on is: Everytime if I recalculate my text I get this "system.windows.controls.textbox:%20" before my url?

Comment: Can't say without seeing code. I guess it would be some small mistake in code. check more, you should be able to resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use 
        string [] split = input.Split(new Char [] {'&'});
And the for each split .Split(new Char [] {'='});
Replace needed values and concat all parts to new string.